# Date serial in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

How can I convert a day [1-31] and a month [1-12] and a year (all int), to a date serial IN SQL (without converting to varchar)?

Comment: By without converting to varchar, you mean that building an ISO date `yyyy-mm-dd` is excluded?

Comment: I know about ISO date. But does it really work? On MS-SQL 2005? And in all possible combinations of languages/cultures (operating system, user, database user, IIS user). Yes I know it is a standard, but I must say I really don't have much faith in so-called standards anymore. Besides, it's faster without varchar.

Comment: What do you mean by "date serial"?

Comment: @onedaywhen: a datetime value. dateserial is the number of miliseconds since 01 Jan 1900, AFAIK.

Comment: Ah, you are from a VBA background, I take it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Zero is 01 jan 1900 in SQL, so you can use this:

```
DATEADD(day, @dayval-1,
     DATEADD(month, @monthval-1,
         DATEADD(year, @yearval-1900, 0)
     )
)
```

Edit, Feb 2018

As the other answer says, since SQL Server 2012 (released after the original answer) we can use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql)

```
 SELECT DATEFROMPARTS (@yearval, @monthval, @dayval)
```

Comment: Commenting here to help others in future as I was having trouble reconciling date serials and this answer helped me figure it out. The date serial in SQL is different to Excel by 1 day!

Answer (score 12):

A few functions have been added in SQL Server 2012 which will allow you to do this with 
[DATEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx), [DATETIMEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213233.aspx) and [TIMEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213398.aspx) amongst others.

Example:

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS(2018,2,1) -- returns 2018-02-01
```