# how to create new date from 3 columns in SQL

Tags: sql, date

i've got columns with `year`, `month` and `day`. how can i put together in `SQL`?

```
SELECT DATA, 
year(data) AS "ROK",  
(month(data)+1) AS "MIESIAC",
day(data) AS "DZIEN"
FROM ZAMOWIENIA
```

Comment: What datatype is the column? If it's not already `DATETIME`, what does it have in it now? What database are you using?

Comment: You have date in 3 columns or you want to get date in 3 columns?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe there is a simpler way.

Comment: If you want a date-serial function; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355015/date-serial-in-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax will depend on your flavor of SQL, but looking at your code I think the simplest solution is to add a month to the data column:

```
SELECT DATA, DATEADD(month, 1, data)
FROM Table
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do that with [concat function](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-concat-function.htm)

examples for [others db](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-concatenate.html) and same result