# How to get last 12 months record from database

Tags: php, codeigniter

hello my question is how to get last twelve months records from database with  if any month have not any record than it should have to returns that month value as 0 .
so how to do this can any one help me to solve this.

i tried following query but it returns only those month records who has records.

```
$query =  $this->db->select('count(*) as count,MONTHNAME(created_at) as months,MONTH(created_at) as month')
                       ->where('created_at >= DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH)')
                       ->group_by('months')
                       ->order_by('month')
                       ->get('users');
```

Comment: Show us your database structure, so people are able to help you better. For now I can say you won't GET the last twelve month, because you COUNT the last twelve months.

Comment: i edit my question ..check it
i want last 12 month record if any month have not record than it should return as 0 of that month value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE dt >=DATEADD(month,-12,DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)) 
AND dt <=DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0)
```

Please refer the below link:

[SQL function for last 12 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493011/sql-function-for-last-12-months)

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND `id`='$id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
# get current Year and month
$currentYear = date("Y");
$currentMonth = date("m");

# set that to filter
$startDate = $currentYear.'01-01'; // output - 2015-01-01
$endDate = $currentYear.'-'.$currentMonth.'-31'; // output - 2015-currentMonth-31

# and your query should be this
$query = $this->db->query(
    "SELECT count(distinct u.id) as monthCount
    FROM users as u
    WHERE created_at >= $startDate 
    AND created_at >= $endDate 
    GROUP BY monthCount
    ");

$result = $query->result_array();
return $result;
```