# How do i get the last 12 months in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have stored procedure that runs every month and i always want to run the rolling 12 months.  I have 2 parameters in my stored procedure, start_date and end_date. For example, my start date and end date for this month should be like this:

```
declare @start_date date
declare @end_date date

set @start_date = '2016-08-01'
set @end_date = '2015-09-01'
exec myStoredProc
 @DateBegin = @start_date
, @DateEnd = @end_date
, @DateType = 'DISCHARGE DATE'
, @ShowAllResultTables = 'N'
```

so my challenge is that i cannot get the start and end date automated so i can pull the rolling 12 months every month.  I am hard coding now.

```
set @start_date = '2016-08-01'
    set @end_date = '2015-09-01'
```

please help.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Declare @Date Date,@DateR1 Date,@DateR2 Date

Set @Date=GetDate()
Set @DateR2=DateAdd(DAY,-Day(@Date)+1,@Date) 
Set @DateR1=DateAdd(MONTH,-13,@DateR2)

Select @DateR1,@DateR2
```

Returns

```
2015-08-01           2016-09-01
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    declare @Date datetime = getdate();

WITH T AS(
SELECT 
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @Date), 0) AS Start,
    DATEADD(d, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,@date)),DATEADD(m,1,@date)) AS EndDate,
    12 Cnt
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    DATEADD(month, -1, Start),
    DATEADD(d, -DAY(DATEADD(m,1,Start-1)),DATEADD(m,1,Start-1)),
    Cnt-1
FROM
    T
WHERE
    Cnt-1>0
)
SELECT 
    Start, EndDate
FROM T
```

[SQL function for last 12 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493011/sql-function-for-last-12-months)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the previous example, this gives end of last month and 12 months back:

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH,-N, CAST(getdate()-(day(getdate())-1) AS date))) as EndOfMonth    
FROM  (VALUES (0), (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11)) t(N);
```