# php and mysql query to get date of the last 12 months

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php function to get dates for a morris pie chart and it was working fine.

But now that I have more data (date for the last year and the first 3 months of this year). It's now displaying duplicate months. In this case february of last year and this years data is now showing on the same pie chart.

I'd like to write a some mysql code in php that will only display the last 12 months. I have the following code:

```
function writesql($rec) {
$year = date('Y') -1;
$month = date('m');
$lastyear = $year - $month; // I know this is a problem.It's subtracting the two variables

$sql = "";
$sql = $sql . " SELECT";
$sql = $sql . " YEAR(`value`)as 'Year',";
$sql = $sql . " MONTH(`value`)as 'Month',";
$sql = $sql . " `value` , ";
$sql = $sql . " COUNT(`value`) as 'Calls' ,";
$sql = $sql . " ROUND(SUM( `value` ),2) as 'Value'";
$sql = $sql . " FROM `table`";
$sql = $sql . " GROUP BY";
$sql = $sql . " YEAR(`value`),";
$sql = $sql . " MONTH(`value`)" ;
$sql = $sql . " ORDER BY";
$sql = $sql . " YEAR(`value`),";
$sql = $sql . " MONTH(`value`)";
$sql = $sql." WHERE (`value`)='".$lastyear."'";// I also know this is wrong too but im lost as to how to fix it.

return $sql;
}
```

Then the rest follows, I only want to get the data for the last 12 months how should I be executing this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL function for last 12 months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20493011/sql-function-for-last-12-months)

Comment: `group by` and `order by` before `where`?

Comment: what is the content of `\`value\``?

Answer (score 3):

You could do `WHERE value >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);`

This would show 12 months up to the current date.

Comment: `NOW()` returns a datetime, it is better to use `CURDATE()`. Try `SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR), DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR);`

Comment: Yes, sorry, this is correct. I'll update my example.

Answer (score 0):

You are close. Make these changes

```
$year = date('Y') -1; // This will give last year

$sql." WHERE YEAR(`value`)='".$year."'"
```

**Updated Query**

```
$sql = "
SELECT YEAR(`value`) as 'Year', MONTH(`value`) as 'Month', `value`,
COUNT(`value`) as 'Calls', ROUND(SUM( `value` ),2) as 'Value'
FROM `table`
WHERE YEAR(`value`) = '$year'
GROUP BY YEAR(`value`), MONTH(`value`)
ORDER BY YEAR(`value`), MONTH(`value`)";
```

Comment: ok just so im clear just put my `$year` variable where i have the `$lastyear` and forget the `$lastyear`?

Comment: No, `WHERE` clause should always come after `FROM` clause. Your query will throw error. Maintain the sequence which I posted.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I find this easier to read:

```
    $sql = "
    SELECT YEAR(value) Year
         , MONTH(value) Month 
         , value
         , COUNT(value) Calls
         , ROUND(SUM(value),2) Value
      FROM `table`
     GROUP 
        BY YEAR(value)
         , MONTH(value)
     ORDER 
        BY YEAR(value)
         , MONTH(value)
     WHERE (value) = '".$lastyear."'
     ";
```

But this query is syntactically incorrect. So here's a syntactically correct version:

```
$sql = "
SELECT YEAR(`value`) Year
     , MONTH(`value`) Month 
     , COUNT(value) Calls
     , ROUND(SUM(value),2) Total_Value
  FROM `table`
 WHERE value = '".$lastyear."'
 GROUP 
    BY YEAR(value)
     , MONTH(value)
 ORDER 
    BY YEAR(value)
     , MONTH(value);
 ";
```

Now see about prepared and bound queries

Comment: so am I correct?, and I just need to have the code syntactically correct?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not psychic, so I couldn't possibly comment. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)