# SQL server 2012 Change int to date <> Saturdays 7

Tags: sql, date

I have a table that doesn't contain a date field but instead contains 3 separate fields:

tDay | tMonth | tYear

These are basic integer fields.

Don't ask but basically the date has been split when the records are added to the table but the original programmer didn't think to add a date field at the same time!

I have a request to only select records where they = (or not <>) a day of the week.

I know how to to the "WHERE DATEPART(dd, date) = 7" bit but I can not figure out a way of combining the 3 fields in the query to make a proper date.

EG

"Where DATEPART(dd, tDay+tMonth+tYear) = 7"

The alternative is to build a new date field from the 3 columns I suppose.

Any suggestions?

Thank you as always for your help

Mal

Comment: If I Google "sql server datetime functions" the top result (on MSDN) answers your question.

Comment: Check gbn's answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355015/date-serial-in-sql

Comment: I have tried DATEPART(dd, CONVERT(datetime, tYear + tmonth + tday )) <> 3 but this still doesn't seem to work...can you point me to correct conversion?...please

Comment: [This is the link I was referring to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186724.aspx#fromParts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the built-in SQL functions to create a proper DateTime from those values.

For example:

```
WHERE DATEPART(dd, DATEFROMPARTS(tYear, tMonth, tDay)) = 7
```

(If you have SQL2012, that is). Otherwise, you'll have to follow Bobby's link:

```
WHERE DATEPART(dd, 
    DATEADD(day, @tDay-1,
        DATEADD(month, @tMonth-1,
            DATEADD(year, @tYear-1900, 0)
        )
    )
) = 7
```

Comment: Thank you for all of you pointing me in the correct direction and giving me the answer.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to "accept" the correct answer, if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try make a datettime string from your data 
then ast it to datettime asnd compare it with datepart function

```
where datepart(dd,cast(REPLICATE(fldYear,1)+'-'+REPLICATE(fldMonth,1)+'-'+REPLICATE(fldDay,1) as datetime) ) =22
```