# How to combine 2 sql queries to one query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures

I'm a bit confused about two SQL queries in MS Access which I have to add in SQL Server.

I want to write a stored procedure, but I don't know how to combine these two sql queries.

Here's the first `MaxMonthDate`:

```
SELECT Max(Day([Datum])) AS DayMax, 
       Month([Datum]) AS MonthMax, 
       Year([Datum]) AS YearMax, 
       DateSerial([YearMax],[MonthMax],[DayMax]) AS DatumMax
FROM DS
WHERE (((DS.Datum)>=[Formulare]![Hauptmenü]![Startdatum] And (DS.Datum)<=[Formulare]![Hauptmenü]![Enddatum]))
GROUP BY Month([Datum]), Year([Datum]);
```

The second query `MaxMonthVal`:

```
SELECT DS.*
FROM MaxMonthDate INNER JOIN DS ON MaxMonthDate.DatumMax = DS.Datum
ORDER BY DS.Datum;
```

Can anyone tell me how to combine these in one query?

Comment: If return columns should be same then you can use "union all"

Comment: Please clarify what is the required output. You can union/union all to combine output of two queries but they should return same columns.

Comment: @AbhayChauhan the first query returns the last day of the month, for example when I try @from = '2014-01-01', @to = '2014-05-31' then it is returning `2014-01-31`, `2014-02-28`, `2014-03-31`... and so on.. The second query returns all columns of this days.

Comment: @MukeshKalgude How can I combine this? Can you give me an example?

Comment: @yuro Is the data returned by the second query the required output?
If that is the case then you can use first query as a subquery to filter data from table DS. Let me know if this is what you are looking for so that I can provide the sample query.

Comment: Refer this link http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union_all.php

Comment: @AbhayChauhan Yes, the second query is required. How can I do a subquery??

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery to combine your queries. Please refer the below query for the same:

```
    SELECT DS.*
    FROM DS where DS.Datum in
    (Select DatumMax from 
    (SELECT Max(Day([Datum])) AS DayMax, 
           Month([Datum]) AS MonthMax, 
           Year([Datum]) AS YearMax, 
           DateSerial([YearMax],[MonthMax],[DayMax]) AS DatumMax
    FROM DS
    WHERE (((DS.Datum)>=[Formulare]![Hauptmenü]![Startdatum] And (DS.Datum)<=[Formulare]![Hauptmenü]![Enddatum]))
    GROUP BY Month([Datum]), Year([Datum]))a
    )
    ORDER BY DS.Datum;
```

Please mark it as answer if it helps you solve your query.

Thanks!!

Comment: The problem is I have to use SQL Server and SQL Server TSQL doesn't contains `DateSerial`

Comment: Use following code instead of dateserial in T-SQL:
DATEADD(day, DayMax-1,
     DATEADD(month, MonthMax-1,
         DATEADD(year, YearMax-1900, 0)
     )
)

Comment: @yuro Were you able to convert dateserial function into T-SQL query?

Comment: DateSerial in TSQL this post here might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355015/date-serial-in-sql