# Transacting MS Access query (using IIF() and DATESERIAL()) into T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, case, iif

I'm trying to convert some MS Access queries to T-SQL to use in SSIS (basically converting Access db to SQL server 2008) and I'm having trouble converting an IIF() statement. I tried several approaches and it always resulted in an error.

The query creates a column with dates that are "original Date + 2 years if the condition is met and original Date + 1 if the condition is not met". The first part of the IIF() eliminates the case of the original year being a leap year and so the possibility of generating a non-existing date.

The original IIF() statement is:

```
IIf((Day(Date)=29 And Month(Date)=2),   
IIf(Desc Like "*" & "123" & "*",
    DateSerial(Year(Date)+2,Month(Date),Day(Date)-1),
    DateSerial(Year(Date)+1,Month(Date),Day(Date)-1)),  
IIf(Desc Like "*" & "123" & "*",
    DateSerial(Year(Date)+2,Month(Date),Day(Date)),
    DateSerial(Year(Date)+1,Month(Date),Day(Date)))) AS Term
```

So the problem is not only an IIF() statement but also DATESERIAL function. I found the solution for the DATESERIAL() function using CAST() (SQL server 2008 does not have the DATEFROMPARTS() function...).

I tried using CASE() like this:

```
CASE
WHEN DAY(Date)=29 AND Month(Date)=2 THEN
    CASE
        WHEN Desc LIKE "%123%" THEN
    CAST(CAST(YEAR(Date)+2 AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(Date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(Date)-1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS DATETIME )
        ELSE CAST(CAST(YEAR(Date)+1 AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(Date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(Date)-1 AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS DATETIME ) END

ELSE CASE
    WHEN Desc LIKE "%123%" THEN
    THEN CAST(CAST(YEAR(Date)+2 AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(Date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(Date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS DATETIME )
    ELSE CAST(CAST(YEAR(Date)+1 AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(Date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) + RIGHT('0' + CAST(DAY(Date) AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) AS DATETIME )END END AS Term
```

I also tried using COAELSCE() but with no better outcome.

I really don't know if I have made some kind of syntax error or where the problem could be.

Thank you in advance for any help.

edit: I'll add error message I'm getting: Incorrect syntax near '...'. The '...' changes as I try different approaches, sometimes its ELSE, THEN etc.

Comment: You are probably aware of that, but `Desc LIKE "123"` should be `Desc LIKE "%123%"` to correspond to your Access query.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that's just a typo here. I'll edit that.

Comment: can you describe what is happening (e.g. error message / wrong results) and how that differs from what you expect?

Comment: I always get an error that says "Incorrect syntax near ELSE/THEN...", I might have mentioned that in the post... I was trying to find an error in the syntax but did not discover any.

Comment: You've got two THEN's next to each other in the final ELSE CASE, but I think there's a simpler way to do this, see my answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server's DATEADD may help to simplify things here...

```
 CASE WHEN (<your condition>) 
 THEN DATEADD(YEAR, 1, [OriginalDate]) 
 ELSE DATEADD(YEAR, 2, [OriginalDate])
 END
```

Should also cope with leap years too.

Comment: Thank you, seems like this works just fine. I can't believe how simple that is and how I spent half a day with my 20 row code...

Answer (score 0):

DateSerial is such a useful function to have around, just create your own.
I got my version from [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/670/DateSerial-Function-for-Microsoft-SQL-Server.html):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.DateSerial
(
  @year int,
  @month int,
  @day int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @date datetime

   -- convert date by adding together like yyyymmdd
   SET @date = cast(@year * 10000 + 101 AS char(8));

   -- Add to date the proper months subtracting 1, since we used 1 as start instead of zero.    
   SET @date = dateadd(mm , @month - 1 , @date)
   -- Add to date the proper days subtracting 1, since we used 1 as start instead of zero.    
   SET @date = dateadd(dd , @day - 1 , @date);

   RETURN @date ;
END;
GO
```

Here is another way: [Date serial in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355015/date-serial-in-sql)

Then use the function just as you did in Access.

Edit: just noticed that your outer IIF is to handle leap years. This is not needed when using `dateadd()`.