# alternative way to TRIM for SSRS (not Crystal Reports)

Tags: t-sql

I imported a report from Crystal to SSRS.

When I run the query in Microsoft Management Console, it throws errors unless I declare variables before the SELECT statement. When I run the query from Visual Studio, it bypasses these variables and only throws an error on the TRIM function.

From what I can tell a JOIN statement may be used instead of a TRIM, but I am not sure.

This is the portion of a where clause that I am trying to change/adapt to work with SSRS, which is throwing an error -- any suggestions appreciated.

Also, I am having issues with the DateSerial in the WHERE clause as follows:

AND (CAST(@StartDate AS Date) <> DateSerial(1900, 01, 01)) AND

Answer (score 0):

Trim does not work in SQL only in the report expressions you would have to use LTrim and RTrim to make this work.

```
AND ( ( NOT ( @Status IS NULL ) 
     AND RTrim(LTrim(@Status)) <> 'All' ) 
    (( ( RTrim(Ltrim(@Status)) = 'Completed' ) 

AND RTrim(LTrim(@AssignedTo)) <> 'All' ) 
            AND ( submission.assignedto IN ( @AssignedTo ) )
```

INCLUDING THE ENTIRE WHERE CLAUSE:

```
WHERE  ( @ParameterIds IS NOT NULL or ParameterIds = @ParameterIds )    
           AND @ParameterIds <> 0 ) 
         AND ( requested_table.parameterid IN ( @ParameterIds ) ) ) 
       AND requested_table.columnname = 'INSERT' 
       AND ( ( NOT ( @Parameter2 IS NULL ) 
              AND Trim(@Parameter2) <> 'All' ) 
             AND (( ( Trim(@Parameter2) = 'Completed' ) 
                    AND (( requested_table.columnname = 'Dup' 
                            OR requested_table.columnname = 'IDup' 
                            OR requested_table.columnname = 'W/D' 
                            OR requested_table.columnname = 'Done' 
                            OR requested_table.columnname = 'QA Review Dup' 
                            OR requested_table.columnname = 'X' )) 
                     OR ( requested_table.columnname IN ( @Parameter2 ) ) )) ) 
       AND ( ( @ParameterIds = 0 ) 
             AND ( ( ( NOT ( @StartDate IS NULL ) 
                       AND ( Cast (@StartDate AS DATE) <> 
                             Dateserial(1900, 01, 01) ) ) 
                     AND ( submission.dateimported >= Datevalue (@StartDate) ) ) 
                   AND ( ( NOT ( @EndDate IS NULL ) 
                           AND ( Cast (@EndDate AS DATE) <> 
                                 Dateserial(1900, 01, 01) ) 
                         ) 
                         AND ( table.dateimported <= Datevalue (@EndDate) ) 
                       ) ) ) 
       AND ( ( @ParameterIds = 0 ) 
             AND (( ( NOT ( @Parameter5 IS NULL ) 
                    AND Trim(@Parameter5) <> 'All' ) 
                    AND ( table.assignedto IN ( @Parameter5 ) ) )) )
```

Fix the Dateserial and this should work.

```
WHERE  ( @ParameterIds IS NOT NULL or ParameterIds = @ParameterIds )    
       AND (@ParameterIds <> 0 ) 
     AND ( requested_table.parameterid IN ( @ParameterIds ) ) 
   AND requested_table.columnname = 'INSERT' 
   AND ( (  (@Parameter2 IS NOT NULL ) 
          AND LTRIM(RTrim(@Parameter2)) <> 'All' ) 
         AND (( ( LTRIM(RTrim((@Parameter2)) = 'Completed' ) 
                AND (( requested_table.columnname = 'Dup' 
                        OR requested_table.columnname = 'IDup' 
                        OR requested_table.columnname = 'W/D' 
                        OR requested_table.columnname = 'Done' 
                        OR requested_table.columnname = 'QA Review Dup' 
                        OR requested_table.columnname = 'X' )) 
                 OR ( requested_table.columnname IN ( @Parameter2 ) ) )) ) 
   AND ( ( @ParameterIds = 0 ) 
         AND ( ( (  ( @StartDate IS NOT NULL ) 
                   AND ( Cast (@StartDate AS DATE) <> 
                         Dateserial(1900, 01, 01) ) ) 
                 AND ( submission.dateimported >=  (@StartDate) ) ) 
               AND ( (  ( @EndDate IS NOT NULL ) 
                       AND ( Cast (@EndDate AS DATE) <> 
                             Dateserial(1900, 01, 01) ) 
                     ) 
                     AND ( table.dateimported <=  (@EndDate) ) 
                   ) ) ) 
   AND ( ( @ParameterIds = 0 ) 
         AND (( (  ( @Parameter5 IS NOT NULL ) 
                AND RTRIM(LTrim(@Parameter5)) <> 'All' ) 
                AND ( table.assignedto IN ( @Parameter5 ) ) )) )
```

Comment: Thank you. I did change this and received this error:

Comment: An error occurred during local report processing.
An error has occurred during report processing.
Query execution failed for dataset 'DataSet1'.
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','. Incorrect syntax near 'RTrim'. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NOT'.

Comment: Well your where clause is a little confusing, I only fixed the Trim function. What are you trying to achieve with your where clause? there are too many Parenthesis that don't match.

Comment: I put the entire WHERE clause up there. My issue is that it worked in Crystal, but SSRS will not take any form of the TRIM function, and seems to have problems with CAST, IN, Dateserial. When I try to run the statement in SQL Server, I have to comment out the parameters .

If I delete the WHERE clause from SSRS, it runs fine. I think I need to fine tune the WHERE clause. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Date serial is another VB function and will not work in SLQ, try this instead- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3355015/date-serial-in-sql  fix the dateserial in the where clause and i think this should work, if not i would tag this with T-SQL as its a T-SQL syntax error not an SSRS Error.

Comment: I changed the CDate, Dateserial, CAST, and Trim function. Now when I am working in SQL Server Management Console, it gives me an error:

Comment: There is no "Order" int he snippet you provided, it may be an error in another part of the query.

Comment: I was able to work through most of my issues. The only remaining one that I can see is that the field in the SQL database, time, is like this: 2012-09-14 09:38:13.000, and my SSRS control for date on the report is like this: 9/14/2012. In which case in SSRS, the Query Parameters Dialog box will not run and says: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: In the SQL, the datetime is handled like this: 

AND (NOT (@StartDate IS NULL)) AND (@StartDate <> CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/1900', 101)) AND 
                         (S.DateinDatabase >= @StartDate) AND (NOT (@EndDate IS NULL)) AND (@EndDate <> CONVERT(DATETIME, '01/01/1900', 101)) AND (S.DateinDatabase <= @EndDate)

Comment: SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 103), ' ', '-')  replace getdate() with S.DateinDatabase and that will format.

Comment: I changed this to:

(NOT (@StartDate IS NULL)) AND (@StartDate <> REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 103), ' ', '-')) AND 
(S.DateinDatabase >= @StartDate) AND (NOT (@EndDate IS NULL)) AND (@EndDate <> REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 103), ' ', '-')) 
AND (S.DateinDatabase <= @EndDate)

and I'm still getting an error, same one: "the string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.